# Extending User Identity to associate permissions in MVC 5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

In MVC (or in ASP.NET), we verify if a user is a member of a particular role with IsInRole method, which is provided default by framework.

For example:

```
 If(User.IsInRole("Admin"))
 {
    // take some action
 }
```

However, I need to check user's permission, for example

```
If(User.HasPermission("Export"))
 {
    // take some action
 }
```

What's the best way of doing it in MVC ?

I have already defined table structure and business logic to define and retrieve permissions. I am just looking a way to associate permission with User object.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Can you  please post your table structure? and also your `HasPermission` method?